# Core Data Directory (tree) Structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, treeview

There are a lot of topics on core data tree structures but I'm left with some questions.

What I'm trying to create is a simple directory structure. (Folders with subfolders with subfolders, ... and later on also files.)

I now have this Folder entity:
[image]

And I'm adding folders like this: *[Obviously this is dummy data and this will be dynamicly inserted later]*

```
// root 1
Folder *root1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Folder" inManagedObjectContext:context];
root1.name = @"Root 1";
root1.parent = nil;

// folder 1 in root 1
Folder *subFolder1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Folder" inManagedObjectContext:context];
subFolder1.name = @"Folder 1 in root 1";
subFolder1.parent = root1;

root1.children = [NSSet setWithObjects: subFolder1, nil];
```

Now I want to make a ViewController for every folder and then open a new ViewController for every subfolder. (Or an infinite UITabelView)

When I loop in the Folder entity with this code:

```
NSArray *folders = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for(Folder *folder in folders){
   NSLog(@"Profile: %@", folder.name);
}
```

I get all the folders at once.

So the question is: How can I log this out in a tree structure? So I can create a ViewController for all the root folders first, and then for every subfolder another ViewController etc. etc...
(In other words: How can I read this entity as I would put it in a UITabelView)

Comment: Use a fetched results controller, save you lots of hassles. In your viewController create an ivar for the parent folder, set this to nil for the first viewController (top level). When you select a folder in the tableView create another instance of the viewController and set its ivar to the selected item (parent) and push it onto the stack.  Use the predicate as described by Tom below.  Using an Array like you are means edits won't automatically be reflected in your UITableViews.  Take a look at the video's here to see an app with this same folder/document structure that uses Core Data.

Comment: Supports drag and drop etc.  You won't find any details on how this hierarchy of folders & documents is implemented on the site but I can add some details if there is any interest.  
http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/os-x-and-ios-app-integration-with-core-data-and-icloud/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't detail how your fetch request is constructed, but the key is to use an `NSPredicate` to filter the results only to include the `Folder` objects of interest at any given time. To do this, you'll need to store a reference to the current parent folder in the view controller:

```
@property (readwrite, strong) Folder *parentFolder;
```

If you're at the root of the tree, this will be `nil`, otherwise it will have a reference to the current folder whose contents you're displaying.

Then use this property in a predicate:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = ...
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent = %@", self.parentFolder];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

When you're at the root, this will select only instances of `Folder` where `parent` is `nil` (i.e. only root level objects). At every other level, it selects only `Folders` where `parent` is whatever the current parent folder is.

As a side note, in your sample code, it's not necessary to set `subFolder1.parent` **and** `root1.children`. Core Data inverse relationship management means that you only need to do this on one side of the relationship. It doesn't hurt anything to do both (aside from a very minor performance hit), but it also serves no purpose.

Comment: If I would add files to those folders, by adding a one-to-many relation Folder.files ->> File.inFolder And both entities Folder and File had and int attribute called 'order' How would I be able to sort both files and folders?

Comment: Look into `NSSortDescriptor`. Also, if your sorting is alphabetical, you don't need an `order` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I need a custom order. The reason I'm struggling with NSSortDescriptor is because folders & files are 2 in different entities but have the order in common.

Comment: You can't do a fetch request covering multiple entities, of course. One option would be to use entity inheritance so that both entities inherit from the same parent, and put the order attribute in the parent. Another would be to do two separate fetches and merge the two resulting arrays into one.

Comment: I think the second option is the easiest for me. Hopefully it won't affect the performance to much. Thanks for your input.